# Prove that $a^{b} +1\geq b(a+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

$a, b \in \mathbb{N} $ and $a>1$,$b>2$

Prove that $a^{b} +1\geq b(a+1)$

My attempt :

suppose $a=p+1$, ($ p \in \mathbb{N}$,$ p\geq 2$)

Remarks :(if $ p=1$ hence $ a=2$,in this case isn't difficult)

So let's show $(p+1)^b +1\geq bp+2b$

We know that $(p+1)^b=\sum_{k=0}^{b}\left( {\begin{array}{c} b \\ k \\ \end{array}} \right) ×p^b\geq \left( {\begin{array}{c} b \\ 1 \\ \end{array}} \right) 
×p+\left( {\begin{array}{c} b \\ b \\ \end{array}} \right) ×p^b$

So $(p+1)^b+1\geq bp+p^b+1\geq bp+2b$

Because $p\geq 2$$\Rightarrow$$ p^b\geq 2^b\geq 2b$

Does my attempt is true?

Comment: This is false. Take $a=b=2$.

Comment: I am edited that b>2

Comment: Should $C^b_k$ and $C^b_1$ be $C^k_b$ and $C^1_b$ respectively?

Answer (score 1):

We can prove this by induction on $b$ when $b\gt2 ,a\gt 1$.

Step 1:

$b=3$, $a^3+1\geq 3a+3$ is easy to prove, note that $a(a^2-3)\geq2$ since $a \geq2$.

Step2:
Now suppose we have $a^b+1\geq ab+b$.

$a^{b+1}+1=a(a^b+1)-a+1$

$ \geq a(ab+b)-a+1=
ab(a+1)-a+1\geq2b(a+1)-a+1$,

and since $b(a+1)-a+1 \gt 2(a+1)-a+1 \gt a+1$,we have $a^{b+1}+1\gt b(a+1)+a+1=(b+1)(a+1)$and we are done.

Comment: Thanks you for your reponse, but just I want to know if my attempt is true,

Comment: @User I think it is right.But maybe you should write $C^{k}_{b}$or$\dbinom{b}{k}$ instead

Comment: Please do you can show me, what is the difference between the both notation

Comment: I think they are the same, it’s just a notation

Comment: Yes I am edited that

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Induction on $b \ge 2$. Can you manage to finish it?

Comment: I am edited that b>2

Comment: I think this should be more of a comment than an answer